# Viabilidade de criar 200 colunas em banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, oracle

Estou planejando um software, que é um teste de 200 questões onde cada questão só pode ter 3 possibilidades de escolha e selecionar apenas uma delas, e cada questão pertence a um tipo de classe ( por exemplo a questão 5 pertence a classe B , são classes de A até J ) e eu preciso salvar o resultado de cada questão no banco de dados, **é viavel criar 200 campos para cada questão**?  Ex:

```
Q1  |  Q2 |  Q3  |  Q4  ......
```

Ou existe algum jeito mais fácil?

Comment: Porque acha que precisa de 200 campos para cada questão só tem 3 opções? Acho que está confundindo as coisas. Não entendi esse negócio de classes. Que resultado? Vai ter outra tabela com as respostas de quem responder? Quais os requisitos dela? Defina melhor o problema, está tudo muito esquisito para poder dizer o que deve fazer. Acho pouco ou nada relevante, mas qual banco de dados vai usar de fato? Ou escolha um ou deixe sem especificar.

Comment: As classes pouco importa, por exemplo: cada questão ou vc pode selecionar inteiro ou real ou nulo, certo ? porém são 200 questões , e preciso guardar o resultado de cada questão para depois poder mostrar em outro sistema , mostrar todas as respostas do usuário ,então eu pensei em criar 200 campos  como por exemplo :                          Tbl_Resposta :nomeUsuario | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4...Q200    <- Campos de uma tabela , gostaria de saber se essa é uma possibilidade viavel para salvar as respostas do usuário

Comment: vc quer saber como modelar no banco? Acho que não precisa de 200 campos para cada questão.. um campo (coluna) já resolve..

Comment: Daniel , eu gostaria de fazer algo deste tipo : http://imgur.com/gobzOMY      pois eu preciso salvar as respostas de vários usuários  , entendeu ? por isso gostaria de saber se fazer  um campo pra cada questão ,até 200 é viavel

Comment: pois bem, o nome disso é "modelagem de dados".. Como eu citei acima, partocularmente, pelo que entendi, não vejo motivo para criar 200 colunas. Uma tabela com uma coluna só já resolve para cadastrar as perguntas e relaciona-las a outras tabelas. Postei resposta descrevendo um resumo.

Comment: Me lembrei desta tirinha  http://vidadeprogramador.com.br/uploads/2016/03/tirinha1545.png , nada pessoal.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza novamente dizendo, a tag adicionada é irrelevante pra pergunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atendendo a questão [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120416/modelagem-do-banco-de-dados)

Você pode criar da seguinte forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tem muito segredo, o que você precisar e ter sua tabela com as perguntas e outras com as opções das pergunta, outra com Usuário, como um usuário pode fazer mais de um teste então você precisa de outra tabela HistoricoTeste e uma tabela para as Respostas, com o modelo acima você pode recupera as informações que um usuário assim.

```
select * from HistoricoTeste ht
join Respostas r
on r.IdHistoricoTeste = ht.IdHistoricoTeste
where ht.IdUsuario = 1 -- usuario
and r.IdPergunta = 1 -- pergunta
```

> Esse é um modelo feito em SQL SERVER.

Comment: Só faltou uma ligação de **Perguntas** para **OpcoesPerguntas  1:N**

Answer (score 6):

Até pode fazer isto mas dificilmente alguém faria em sã consciência. A grosso modo o correto seria:

```
CREATE TABLE Resultado (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Usuario int,
    Questao int,
    Resposta int,
);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Questions.sql).

Botei tudo `int` por falta de ter uma informação melhor de como isto seria composto. Obviamente seria interessante ter uma tabela de usuário e uma de questões para fazer referência.

Algumas pessoas prefeririam não ter o `ID` e usar a combinação de `Usuario`+`Questao` como chave primária.

Obviamente que se tiver uma razão para criar 200 colunas, pode fazer também, mas precisa ter certeza que é a melhor opção, tem que saber justificar isto. Duvido que seja.

Answer (score 3):

Parece meio bobo postar isso, mas uma estrutura lógica e básica seria algo assim:

```
# Todas as perguntas
tabela perguntas
 - id (único)
 - descricao

# Todas as respostas, independente da pergunta
tabela respostas
 - id (único)
 - descricao

# Quais respostas estarão disponíveis para cada pergunta
tabela perguntas_respostas
 - id (único)
 - perguntas_id
 - respostas_id

# Todos os usuários
tabela usuarios
 - id (único)
 - nome

# Quais respostas que o usuário escolheu relacionado com a pergunta: 
tabela usuarios_respostas
 - id (único)
 - perguntas_id
 - respostas_id
 - usuarios_id
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então você criaria um CRUD para gerenciar as perguntas e as respostas

Mas não está claro o que pretende fazer. Há formas diversas para resolver. Não quer dizer que o exemplo sugerido seja o ideal e tampouco o melhor.

<sub>CRUD (Create, Read, Updade, Delete)</sub>